# What other Italian cheese(s) could be substituted for parmesan in most recipes?

Tags: cheese, pasta

I seem to be unable to tolerate Parmesan cheese (not the processed "parmesan-flavored" cheese, but the real Italian Parmesan) - as a topping it makes me gag, and if included in a recipe either nauseates me or gives me a stomach ache.  I have no trouble with Romano, Asiago, Auribella, etc.  Just the Parmesan.  What cheese (or combination of cheeses) could I substitute for Parmesan in most recipes and still get a good result?  thanx much!

Comment: Personally I love Romano and Asiago so I will use them over Parmesan whenever I can!  I don't dislike Parmesan, just like the others better.  You could easily use either or both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Pecorino Romano has a similar texture and umami, but slighly different flavor profile.  It is used in many Italian dishes like Parmesan is used.  You could also look for Grana Padano as a less complex substitute for Parm.